# kotlin の日付処理で今日の日付を取得できない

Tags: android, kotlin

kotlinの日付処理で困っています。

エラーは何も出ずにビルド可能なのですが、以下が動作しません。

```
import org.threeten.bp.*
 
val nowDate = LocalDateTime.now()
val nowDate = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"))
```

デバッガーを貼ると `DispatchedTask.kt` に飛ばされてよく分からないです。

Comment: ThreeTenABP を利用していてクラッシュする、という情報を検索すると大抵 [`AndroidThreeTen.init(this)`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#usage) の呼び忘れが原因のようですが、こちらは行われているでしょうか。

Comment: 呼んでいなかったです。
処理の直前で呼ぶと、(this)の部分でエラーになります。
onCreateの中でなくてonActivityCreatedの中で呼んでいるからでしょうか？

Comment: （DispatchedContribution@22014）というエラーです。

Comment: 非同期処理の中で呼んでいるからかもしれませんが、非同期処理の外で呼んでも状況は変わらず。。
※あまり詳しくなく、的外れなことを言っていたらすみません。

Comment: 問題が再現できるコード(や手順)を質問文中で提示したほうが良いかと考えます。(コメントを読む限り、質問文の内容だけでは情報が不足しているように感じます)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

根本的な解決には至っていませんが、ひとまず `Date()` を使ってうまく代用することにしました。